# Why can't I set value to display in a div?

Tags: javascript

So I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to figure out why doesn't this work:

My function has this line:

```
document.getElementById("displayResult").value = ("test");
```

and this is my div:

```
<div id="displayResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

div's don't have a `value` property. You want to set the `.innerText` property.

And by all means, have fun testing things yourself, but you'll find it a lot easier if you use a framework to do these things (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com))

Comment: Don't capitalise the I on innerText. Javascript is case sensitive, and  generally functions and variables are written in camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use - .innerHTML no?

```
document.getElementById("displayResult").innerHTML = "<b>test</b>";
```

Comment: For this little example, JQuery is not required.  However, you should definitely check out JQuery, Prototype, etc.

Answer (score 1):

.value is only a valid attribute on form fields. You likely want to use the following code:

`document.getElementById("displayResult").innerHTML = "test";`

Answer (score 0):

you have to test if innerHTML is supported by your brwser. As it is not the DOM Standard.
You can write it like

```
var oDiv = document.getElementById("displayResult")

if(typeof oDiv.innerHTML != undefined) {
      oDiv .innerHTML = message;
    } else {
      oDiv .appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
}
```